# Aiogram -- set state for a exact user

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a bot in python and aiogram. The point is that the administrator accepts (or rejects) user requests. Accordingly, when the administrator clicks on the button in his chat, I need to change the user's state (his uid is known). I didn't find how to do it anywhere.

I'm looking for something like

```
dp.set_state(uid, User.accepted))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. please remove the `python-telegram-bot` tag, as that's for a different library ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext

@dp.message_handler(state='*')
async def example_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    new_state = FSMContext(storage, chat_id, user_id)
```

then `set_state()` and `set_data()` on the `new_state`.

`storage` is the FSM storage.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem

Found method set() in base class State:

```
class State:
    ...
    async def set(self):
        state = Dispatcher.get_current().current_state()
        await state.set_state(self.state)
```

So I created new class from State and overrode method this way:

```
    async def set(self, user=None):
        """Option to set state for concrete user"""
        state = Dispatcher.get_current().current_state(user=user)
        await state.set_state(self.state)
```

Usage:

```
@dp.message_handler(state='*')
async def example_handler(message: Message):
    await SomeStateGroup.SomeState.set(user=message.from_user.id)
```

If you want some mailing stuff, collect user ids and use that hint.

Answer (score 2):

**For new Aiogram 3.1.0**

As Aiogram 3.1.0 has slightly different methods of accessing storage and context, I would like to share what I came up with:

```py
from aiogram.fsm.storage.base import StorageKey
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext


class UserState(StatesGroup):
    # any other states
    EXPIRED = State()


bot = Bot("your_token", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
storage = MemoryStorage()  # for clarity it is created explicitly
dp = Dispatcher(storage=storage)
# here goes the desired userId and chatId (they are same in private chat)
new_user_storage_key = StorageKey(bot.id, user_id, user_id)
new_user_context = FSMContext(storage=storage, key=new_user_storage_key)
await new_user_context.set_state(UserState.EXPIRED)  # your specified state
```

> User's own storage (MemoryRecord) is now accessed by ***StorageKey***
> instead of just user_id, that's why it is necessary to create it
> first, after that fill it with values (IDs) and then pass it to the
> FSMcontext. After the context is created, calling **set_state(...)**
> and **set_data(...)** will set state/data specifically for the
> desired user_id.

Actually there is no need to create a storage explicitly as shown in the previous code snippet, as it will be created automatically, so you can just access it by **dispatcher.storage** property like here:

```py
# the same imports
# the same UserState class

bot = Bot("your_token", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher()  # we don't create storage manually this time
# here goes the desired userId and chatId (they are same in private chat)
new_user_storage_key = StorageKey(bot.id, user_id, user_id)
new_user_context = FSMContext(storage=dp.storage, key=new_user_storage_key)
await new_user_context.set_state(UserState.EXPIRED)  # your specified state
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
state = dp.current_state(chat=chat_id, user=user_id) 
await state.set_state(User.accepted)
```

`dp` - an object of the Dispatcher class
`chat_id` - chat id, which must be equal to the user id if this is a correspondence with a user
`User.accepted` - the state we want to bring the user to

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).